# sending updated list of online and offline chat users from php to ios

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I am a php developer. I have a DB table(mysql) where username and their online status(either 1 or 0) is storing. Now I have to send the list of online users to ios, so that every moment ios can get updated record.

If ios sends request to server after every second then obviously, the data, which will be visible in ios side, would be updated.
But, I don't want this option. 
If any changes occur in server side, then only ios can put a request to server and server will give response to ios. This is my plan. For that I thought APNS would be better. But when I came to know, its also not much efficient specially for showing online chat users, I think there should be another methodology or mechanism so that instead of using APNS, I can fix my issue.

Please suggest me which one would be better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need web socket communication. Give [PHPWebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) a try.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but could you please explain it how to connect to each other or could you please provide any link from where I can get some idea about this. Actually I am not flexible with sockets program.

Answer (score 0):

You have options like phpWebSocke In which your client have to ping or send socket request to server. the same approach as you are describing in your question.

All though APNS is not 100% guaranteed that your client device get your message.

I highly suggest you to go for open source jabber server and client api(XMPP). `OpenFire` and 'Smack' & 'smackx' API will handle every thing behalf of you. and its open source. so no need to worry about license and no need to re-invent the wheel.

here is the links.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/index.jsp

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/xmppframework/ctp5uTUau3M

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Nut I think, jabber server restricts upto MobileMe, Mac.com,AIM, Google Talk and jabber accounts. 
Actually I have already a DB table where user's session ID and device ID are capturing and storing to table. For that OpenTok is using.
So in this scenario, please let me know whether jabber server will work or not?

Comment: Okey, Now I am not getting your point. See, You have to install a `openfire` server(XMPP sever),configure it. then all you need is download API for iOS(XMPP Client )Jabber,smackx,smack.In this api you can send Add friend request, you can show list of pending reqeust. or pending chat sent. show online users. set the status... everything. API is also available for IOS,Android,Blackbaryy,Desktop client,Windows Phone.

Comment: But there is no email address available in my application, only sessionID and deviceID and enablestatus are there. SO then also can I use it?

Comment: To create a user in open fire you need to create unique id for the user.It doesn't it must be email address. Yes.. you can create a user without email address.